# Azure function not able to run locally due to file path?

Tags: azure, .net-core, youtube-api, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

When I upload a new video into my Azure Blob container, I would like to have that video also be uploaded to my YouTube channel automatically using a Azure Logic app.

To do this, first I have created this Azure function, which contains the code to upload a video to my YouTube channel automatically (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert). I made this as HTTP trigger function (not sure if this is the right trigger to use), and this function should get triggered when there is a new video uploaded in my Azure Blob container.

When I run the app, I am getting an error:

> Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=84400f0c-b6e4-4c78-bf55-30c4527a8b5f)
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1.
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\TestDemo\UploadVideo\UploadVideo\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\client_secrets.json'.

**Question**: What does that error mean? How do I refactor the code, to make this an accessible file path, so that whenever there is a new video in Azure blob container, this functions gets triggered and uploads video to my YouTube Channel?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Threading;

namespace UploadVideo
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            log.LogInformation("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
            log.LogInformation("==============================");

            try
            {
                await Run();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    log.LogInformation("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            return new OkObjectResult($"Video Processed..");

        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                    // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
            var filePath = @"C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\audio\test.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }
        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                    break;

                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work on Azure, but not on you local machine - or?

Comment: @FrankNielsen I tried it on my local first and it's throwing an error their itself. I am not sure if my GET request is wrong, or my code is wrong. This is the GET request I am inputing:  http://localhost:7072/api/Function1

Comment: Yes, but you are doing a `FileStream("client_secrets.json"` so it loads the file relative/path of execution. The path you show in the exception is on your local machine i guess?!

Comment: @FrankNielsen, yes I checked, the path is on my local machine? How can I fix this?

Comment: If the above statement works in Azure(?), and you only have problem running locally you might use compile directives `#if DEBUG` and hard coding another path within that.

Comment: @FrankNielsen, when you say does it work in Azure, how would I check that?Also how is this code (above) going to upload a video to my youtube channel?

Comment: Can you show your compilation folder, and are you sure the file exists? Did you forget 'Copy if newer'. Or did you add extra .json? Please show your compilation folder, one of you and the computer must be wrong.