# How to use Azure Logic app to upload videos that are in Azure Blob storage to YouTube directly

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to export videos that are on Azure Blob storage, to my YouTube Channel automatically? I am thinking whether logic app and connectors can be used to automate this process? Or is there another way using  Azure.

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm afraid there are no actions in logic app which can do this operation automatically. Azure logic app has the "YouTube" connector but there are no actions in it(it has just three triggers). So if you want to do it by logic app, you can just call the api(by "http" action in logic app) which you used in function.

Comment: @HuryShen, I have tried to do this using Azure function but running into an error. Do you mind taking a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288693/azure-function-not-able-to-run-locally-due-to-file-path?noredirect=1#comment106645651_60288693 . Thank you.

Comment: @HuryShen, any help on this would be appreciated:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60288693/12430088

Comment: The only way that would work is if you could make a file stream / memory stream to the file on Azure blob storage.  I have never managed to get upload to work from another place than where the code is running normally i send the files from the server wehre they are currently stored.